# Remove all but few specific pattern of files in Linux

Tags: linux, rm

I have the following requirement.

**

**=> Shell snippet**

**
**%** ls

```
c.log.1   c.log.11  c.log.13  c.log.15  c.log.17  c.log.19  c.log.20  c.log.22  c.log.24  c.log.26  c.log.28  c.log.3   c.log.31  c.log.4  c.log.6   c.log.8   c.log.10  c.log.12  c.log.14  c.log.16  c.log.18  c.log.2   c.log.21  c.log.23  c.log.25  c.log.27  c.log.29  c.log.30  c.log.32  c.log.5   c.log.7   c.log.9
```

I need to delete all files except say, **For ex:** c.log.7 or any such specific file.

Kindly provide the solution.

Thanks,
Vinod.R.M

Comment: take a look at below link, same question is repeated <http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153862/remove-all-files-directories-except-for-one-file>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -1 |grep -w -v 'c.log.7'|xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: Hi Vijay,

Thanks for your response.
One other query. What if there are multiple other files in the same directory, along with c.log.* files. How do I ensure that I delete only c.log.* files without c.log.7

Comment: `ls -1 c.log.* |grep -w -v 'c.log.7'|xargs rm -rf`

Comment: careful wirh `-rf`

Comment: Thanks a lot Vijay!